Cartoon series about a boy travelling around a fictitious world on possibly an airship
I am super vague about all details of this cartoon from when I was a kid, apart from one episode.
In the episode, the boy arrives to an unstable floating island in the sky. The inhabitants of the island are cranky because they are unable to sleep and their movements are timed. This was because there were afraid of the island tipping over in the sky causing them to fall off.
The solution at the end of the episode, which was proposed by the boy, was that they build their houses on the outer rim of the floating island, which allows them to keep a better balance and live more freely without constant concerns of it tipping. Once done, the boys departs with the inhabitants catching up on long lost sleep.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?
